# Finding all flights for a given day with Amadeus GDS

Tags: air-travel, gds

Using Amadeus GDS console, is there a host command that will return a list of all flights for a given day, operated/marketed by a given airline/carrier?

Comment: wouldn't it return a list that is too long for the display in the console? I would expect many commands a bit more restrictive like @HaLaBi suggested

Comment: Other GDS systems have such command and it returns response in multiple pages, and you can move between pages.

Answer (score 4):

I am not the master when it comes to Amadeus, I had one week of training (very basic) out of curiosity a few years ago, I still remember some of the cryptic commands.

To get the schedule for a specific route and specific airline for a day:

```
TN15NOVJFKIAD/ADL
```

- `TN`: the timetable command
- `15NOV`: the date (`ddMMM`)
- `JFKIAD`: the route
- `/ADL:` *[optional]* `DL` is the airline code (Delta in this case) and `A` is a prefix. If you do not specify this it will show all airlines.

I am not aware of a command that gives a list of flights without specifying the route, but there could be one.

Comment: Thank you. Right, a command that does not take a route would be fine. I went through 
[Amadeus Advanced Manual](http://www.amadeus.com/lt/documents/Amadeus%20Advanced%20Manual.pdf) and [The Complete Amadeus Manual](http://www.air.flyingway.com/books/amadeus/Amadeus_Guide.pdf) but don't know whether they are really complete. I've seen similar command in other RES so I wonder if Amadeus has it as well.